# Print only that which is from start till to the end point

Tags: perl, sed, awk, grep

Want to print only that which is from start till to the end point

Example:

```
Started at Mon Nov 25 14:30:02 ALMT 2013
Load average for db1 is 10 which is less than 100
Load average for db2 is 3 which is less than 100
Load average for db3 is 6 which is less than 100
Load average for db4 is 5 which is less than 100
Load average for db5 is 5 which is less than 100
Mon Nov 25                                                                                 page
some other data
some other data
some other data
```

Expected:

```
Started at Mon Nov 25 14:30:02 ALMT 2013
Load average for db1 is 10 which is less than 100
Load average for db2 is 3 which is less than 100
Load average for db3 is 6 which is less than 100
Load average for db4 is 5 which is less than 100
Load average for db5 is 5 which is less than 100
Mon Nov 25                                                                                 page
```

I try with that:

```
perl -0777 -lpe 's|Started .*? page||xsg' 1
```

But that delete whole area which I want to print.

Comment: Err I don't see any end point.

Comment: just scroll to the right there are "Started at ..." and finish is "25                                                                                 page"

Comment: So the "end" of your record is the date in the "Started" line, followed by the string "page"? With a massive amount of whitespace before "page"? You have to be specific, because we can't read your mind: You have to tell us what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or with [sed](/questions/tagged/sed). But note that if the "start" tag is encountered but not the "end", it will print everything from the start tag to the end of file

```
sed -n '/^Started/, /page/p' file
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like it could make it:

```
$ awk '/^Started/ {p=1} p; /page$/ {p=0}' file
Started at Mon Nov 25 14:30:02 ALMT 2013
Load average for db1 is 10 which is less than 100
Load average for db2 is 3 which is less than 100
Load average for db3 is 6 which is less than 100
Load average for db4 is 5 which is less than 100
Load average for db5 is 5 which is less than 100
Mon Nov 25                                                                                 page
```

- `/^Started/ {p=1}` when it finds a string starting with "Started", then the flag `p` is set to 1.
- `p` prints the line in case the flag `p` is true.
- `/page$/ {p=0}` when it finds a string ending with "page", then the flag `p` is set to 0.

---

Also, ([thanks 1_CR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20196734/print-only-that-which-is-from-start-till-to-the-end-point/20196882#comment30112213_20196882)):

```
awk '/^Started/,/page$/' file
```

Comment: Strange is not working on my console, just print all output :/

Comment: Check if your sample input matches the following: one line starts with  "Started" and one line ends with "page".

Comment: Wow, that's way shorter, @1_CR! Thanks a lot, I add it as another option and +1 your answer, as it is also using this logic.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$ perl -0777 -lpe 's|.*(Started .*? page).*|$1|xsg' 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -0777 -ne 'print /(Started .*? page)/xsg' 1
```